# Typecasting and instanceof operator

Tags: java

In the below code what exactly is the function of instanceof operator? I understand that if block executes only if  its true i.e (obj instanceof  MountainBike==true).Assuming its true why does we should again typecast (MountainBike)obj?

```
    if (obj instanceof MountainBike) {
      MountainBike myBike = (MountainBike)obj;
     }
```

Comment: It says "If the object *can* be seen as a MountainBike, get a view of it as MountainBike".

Comment: I assume obj is of type "Object" which is the parent of all objects. If you don't cast you will not be able to use functions from MountainBike class ie the child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the compiler does not know, at compile time, that this object is a "MountainBike", so a cast is needed